# How to Upload excel data to mysql database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have codeigniter application, Now i need to Upload excel using the codigniter. 
How to do that. I follow some Online tutorials, but there are not complete one. Specially there are no what is the library they use.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

{
    $mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$mimes))
    {
       $uploadFilePath = 'uploads/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

```
   $filename = pathinfo($uploadFilePath);

   $f = array("name"=>$filename['filename']);

   foreach ($f as $k)
   {
     $policy = $k;
   }

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadFilePath);
   $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($uploadFilePath);
   $totalSheet = count($Reader->sheets());
    //echo "You have total ".$totalSheet." sheets".

    /* For Loop for all sheets */
    for($i=0;$i<$totalSheet;$i++)
    {
        $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
        foreach ($Reader as $Row)
        {
            $treeno ++;

            $policyno = isset($Row[0]) ? $Row[0] : '';
            $act_treeno = isset($Row[1]) ? $Row[1] : '';
            $dbh = isset($Row[2]) ? $Row[2] : '';
            $height = isset($Row[3]) ? $Row[3] : '';

            $pno = substr($policyno, -6);
            $treeno = $pno.'_'.$act_treeno.'_T';

           $query = "insert into tbl_trees(policyno,actual_treeno,dbh,height,treeno) values('".$policyno."','".$act_treeno."','".$dbh."','".$height."','".$treeno."')";
           echo '</br>';
           $mysqli->query($query);
```

this is work, but i have not idea to use this method in codeigniter.

Comment: Export to CSV and use MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: @Phil, that can do me as a developer. but i need to make and interface to use that for my client, i have and script upload excel, but not using codigniter.

Answer (score 0):

First think you need upload that file then try open and prepare data for insert-

```
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploadData = array();
    if (!empty($fileName)) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './your location/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|csv|xls|xlsx';
        $config['max_size'] = 2048;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
            json_error("File Upload Error", $this->upload->display_errors(), 400);
        } else {
            $uploadData = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        }
    }//if
```

prepare data for insert-

```
if (!empty($uploadData)) {
        $fileName = $uploadData['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $data = array(); //empty array;
        $fileInfo = fopen(base_url() . 'your file location/' . $fileName, "r");

        $i = 0;
        while (!feof($fileInfo)) {
            $colInfo = fgets($fileInfo); //fgets means read file in line by line.

            //prefer data to save
            $data[$i]['your_column'] = $colInfo;
            $i++;

        }//while
        fclose($fileInfo);
    }
```

insert batch data-

```
$this->db->insert_batch('dbtable', $data);
```

Comment: actually you don't need model view controller i already give you all code that you need, your take a file input field in a form then submit to a function, and put my all code hope it work